# How can I set the language of Safari and launch using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, selenium3

I need to launch the Safari browser for automation with a specific language(Korean) for automation purpose. I am using selenium with python for automation. How can I do that ?

Comment: I have heard we cant change the language alone for Safari. Is it true ?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome offers a modification of desired capabilities and I believe all the modern web browsers will also do. I did not try particularly with Safari web driver.

Did you try desired capabilities to change the accept_languages": "Korean" using safari web driver.

Also, If you have tests verifying the content in the specific language, automating with Selenium will give you hard time going forward. Checking language specific content against your expected result(assuming hardcoded expected content) will fail for even minor changes.

If you have the choice to try with new tools, try with tools like applitools.